# Is it possible to get a value from the numberFormat (NetSuite) field and use it in the code?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

Is it possible to get the value from NUMBERFORMAT field and use it in custom code?
I wrote a pdf document in the code and I'd like to include the number format that is set in the Set Preferences tab. I would like to know if this is possible and how could I do it?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> var userPref = nlapiLoadConfiguration('userpreferences');
> var numFormat = userPref.getFieldText('numberformat');
> ```

Here is 1.0 approach.

Comment: Result from numFormat is 1 000 000,00 - its the same number i have in number format preferences settings. How can i trun this string format into number format for my amounts on the worksheet?

Comment: Hi @Tenecious, not sure what exactly you want accomplish. did you mean from "1 000 000,00" to "100,000,000.00"?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I've already solved my problem. I have created a function that retrieves its digits for a given format. In the second function, I substitute these digits in the appropriate place for the amount. A bit confusing, however, I came across this. Maybe there is another way to do it. Easier one?

Comment: You can try N/format api, you can find 1.0/2.0 map in Suite Helper. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use the `N/config` module to retrieve this information:

```
define(['N/config'], function(config) {

    // Add some entry point function here

    function getUserNumberFormat() {
      var generalPrefs = config.load({ type: 'userpreferences', isDynamic: true });    
      return generalPrefs.getText('NUMBERFORMAT');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i need something in SuiteScript 1.0. Do you know how to do it this way?